# 3ds Max - How to Cross Edges

Tags: 3dsmax

I' relatively new to modeling, so this might be a simple question to answer. I'm having trouble trying to cross edges. I've placed a screenshot below of what I'm trying to accomplish (made in SketchUp). It's a box with to edges along the diagonals of each face. Is there a simple way to do this in 3ds Max? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: A comment here, since it's not exactly clear from your wording: you've got four edges that meet in a vertex at the center of each face. No two edges actually cross in your picture; indeed, it's generally a bad idea for edges to cross at all, since that means there are multiple overlapping faces that would be prone to z-fighting.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think of, neither of which are particularly clever but will do it:

1. Apply the 'Subdivide' modifier and just increase/reduce the 'Size' parameter (very roughly) until your polys have been split correctly.
2. Convert to Editable Poly (or the selected faces will be triangles), select the face(s) and use 'Insert Vertex' to split them.

These of course work well for creating the box you describe but perhaps you could explain what the end goal of crossing the edges is (e.g. add detail?) as there might be a better solution for a more complex model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, this method takes approximately 1 minute when you know the steps by memory.

1. Create a box using keyboard entry.
2. Set the X,Y,Z all to 0.
3. Set the width, length, height all to 2.
4. Set the length, width, height segments all to 1.
5. Turn on the move snap toggle. (The icon in the top bar with the
   number "3" and a magnet on it.)
6. Now convert the box to editable poly and go to polygon selection
   mode.
7. Click "Insert vertex" in the modify pane with polygon selection mode
   set.
8. Now using the top/left/front orthographic views, click to add a
   vertex at the center of each cube face (which is easy because you
   have snapping turned on).

The desired edges are automatically added when you add these vertices.